# How to use two DataTextField and DataValueField in one ComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, button, combobox

Using: C# | asp.net

What I want to do is take one ComboBox and one Button. I want the ComboBox to read two different datasets for DataValueField and populate the drop down list with whichever DataValueField isn't empty.

The two datasets will have different DataTextFields so I need the ComboBox to also check and populate the ComboBox with the DataTextField that isn't empty. Is this possible?

So far I have the ComboBox populating the DataValueField for one of the datasets but not both. I'm not sure if I should use OnSelectedIndexChanged or something different or if this is even possible? Any advice will be welcomed! Thanks.

**.aspx**

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
        DataSourceID="SQLserver" 
          DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" MaxLength="0" 
          style="display: inline;">
</asp:ComboBox>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void Button1_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
          {
            if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
           {
                bool img = true;
                string Path = "URL" + ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Value;

                if (img == true)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "openFoundImage", "window.open('" + Path + "');", true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you concatenate the two datasets, then bind it to the ComboBox?

Comment: I dont want the choices to show if the dataset is empty. I want the combobox to populate with one of the two, not both. @Garrison

Comment: But if one of the datasets is empty, you could use code-behind to check for that, then bind the other one.  You can't have two datasets to a combobox, but you can programmatically determine which one to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a model class and can bind your combobox with that. Assign value to the model according to the availability of data in the two dataset.. This way is easy and won't lead to
 much complications. Simple way and code will also be manageable.

Hope fully it will do the need full.